# Calculating the odds of winning a game

Tags: combinations, game-theory, combinatorial-game-theory

**Problem:** You, the user have 3 lives. In front of you are 5 cups - in each cup there is a piece of paper with 1 random number between 1 and 5 (inclusive) written on it.

You must guess the number in each cup, one at a time. If you get one wrong the numbers are randomized again and you must start from the beginning.

To win, you must guess all 5 numbers correctly before losing all 3 lives.

---

**My question is:** How do I calculate the odds of winning?

I think I've calculated that given there are 5 possible numbers for each of the 5 cups there are 53,130 different combinations.

Given that you have 3 lives, does that mean the odds of getting correct are 3 in 53,130?

Comment: How did you get the number $53130$?

Comment: Start by finding the probability of winning with only one life.

Comment: Does every cup have a different number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not clear whether each cup has a different number or whether each cup has a $\frac{1}{5}$ chance of having any given number.

In the second case, the chance of correctly guessing the number in one cup is $\frac{1}{5}$, so the chance of correctly guessing the number in all five cups is $\frac{1}{5^5}=\frac{1}{3125}$. So the chance of losing a life in making an attempt is $1-\frac{1}{5^5}=\frac{3124}{3125}$. So the chance of losing three lives is $(1-\frac{1}{5^5})^3$. The chance of success is $1-(1-\frac{1}{5^5})^3=\frac{29287501}{30517578125}\approx0.1\%$.

In the first case, the chance of correctly guessing the first cup is $\frac{1}{5}$, the chance of correctly guessing the second is $\frac{1}{4}$ and so on. So the chance of correctly guessing them all is $\frac{1}{120}$. So the chance of losing a life is $\frac{119}{120}$. Hence the chance of losing three lives is $\left(\frac{119}{120}\right)^3=\frac{1685159}{1728000}$. So the chance of success is $1-\left(\frac{119}{120}\right)^3=\frac{42841}{1728000}\approx2.5\%$

Comment: Thanks for this! 

Each cup has $\frac{1}{5}$ of having any given number so it looks like you have approximately 0.1% chance of winning. Is that right?

Comment: Correct. Seems rather too discouraging for an enjoyable game!

Comment: How would this change if the user didn't have to restart upon a wrong guess?

Comment: You mean if, for example, he had already guessed 4 cups correctly, he would just lose a life and have to guess again for the 5th cup? Would the 5th cup be chosen afresh, or would he know that it could not be any numbers he had already chosen?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. The 5th cup isn't affected by the 4th at all. So it's still $\frac{1}{5}$ chance of guessing correctly.

Comment: That looks like $\frac{1}{5^5}+5\frac{4}{5}\frac{1}{5^5}+15\frac{4^2}{5^2}\frac{1}{5^5}=0.47\%$. [He must make five correct guesses before making three incorrect guesses, the first term no incorrect guesses, the second is one incorrect guess, the third is two incorrect guesses.]